# save images in cache android

Tags: android, performance

My android project layout xml file has three button. which are shows, events & home. when buttons click they download images from url & save them in cache. So now downloaded are completed once it is clicked. when click the shows button again it must show the downloaded images taking from cache.

The problem is I download all the images in one cache dir. when button click separately they load default images. because can't identify images. my code as following way.

```
public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/shows");
            cacheDirEvent=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/events");
            cacheDirPromotion=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/promotion");
        }
        else{
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
            cacheDirEvent=context.getCacheDir();
            cacheDirPromotion=context.getCacheDir();
        }
        if(!cacheDir.exists()&& !cacheDirEvent.exists() && !cacheDirPromotion.exists()){
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
            cacheDirEvent.mkdir();
            cacheDirPromotion.mkdir();
        }
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }
```

pls help me. i'm stuck with this question

After that I have done this. but same answer.......why is it?

```
public FileCache(Context context,int i){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)&& i==3)
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/shows");
        else if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)&& i==2)
            cacheDirEvent=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/events");
        else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && i==1)
            cacheDirHome=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/home");
        else 
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
            cacheDirEvent=context.getCacheDir();
            cacheDirHome=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        else if (!cacheDirHome.exists())
            cacheDirHome.mkdirs();
        else if  (!cacheDirEvent.exists())
            cacheDirEvent.mkdirs();

    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        if(url.substring(0, 26).equals("http://tnlradio/promotions")){
        File f = new File(cacheDirHome, filename);
        return f;}
        else if(url.equals("http://stream.tnlradio.com/images/dilshan-ishara.jpg")){
            File f = new File(cacheDirEvent, filename);
            return f;}
        else{
            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
            return f;
        }

    }
```

pls help me

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example for this. [Caching Bitmaps.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) They tell you how to do a memory cache as well as disk cache.

Comment: what would you recommend for what might be a large number of photos that I need to save? I want as low as possible space used but with some decent performance at reading it. Writhing speed is also something important.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu That will probably depend on the sizes of the images.  If these will be JPEGs, I would say a disk cache can have quite a few, maybe even 100?  As for a memory cache, they take up quite a bit of space in memory. You may want to only memory cache what is currently being shown and maybe a little farther, depending on the image size.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a quick and dirty solution you can store the mapping between file and url in shared preferences like this:

```
public class FileCache
{
    private File                cacheDir;
    private File                cacheDirEvent;
    private File                cacheDirPromotion;

    public FileCache(final Context context)
    {
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            this.cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TNLRadio/res/shows");
            this.cacheDirEvent = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TNLRadio/res/events");
            this.cacheDirPromotion = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            "TNLRadio/res/promotion");
        }
        else
        {
            this.cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
            this.cacheDirEvent = context.getCacheDir();
            this.cacheDirPromotion = context.getCacheDir();
        }
        if (!this.cacheDir.exists() && !this.cacheDirEvent.exists() && !this.cacheDirPromotion.exists())
        {
            this.cacheDir.mkdirs();
            this.cacheDirEvent.mkdir();
            this.cacheDirPromotion.mkdir();
        }
    }

    public File getFile(final Context context, final String url) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // retrieve filename/location from shared preferences based on the the url
        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String filename = settings.getString(url, null);

        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        final File f = new File(this.cacheDir, filename);
        return f;
    }

    public void downloadAndCache(final Context context, final String url)
    {
        // TODO: download the file and save to the filesystem
        // TODO: generate a the filename and push into saved preferences
        String filename = "";

        // save file into the share preferences so we can get it back late
        saveFileToMap(context, url, filename);
    }

    private void saveFileToMap(final Context context, final String url, final String filename)
    {
        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        // save the pair into shared preferences
        final Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(url, filename);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: will the images be available when you are offline, with the url saved?

Comment: Yes, with cache's you should always check for the file in the cache before trying to download it.  Therefore it is in the cache it will not require an internet connection